# how to export code from visual studio as a document

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a code that I need to put in a document for my coursework but I would like to keep all the formatting and line numbers. Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy and paste it.

Ms Word will retain the formatting.

Other text editors might as well.

Comment: that does not keep the line numbers

Comment: I'm afraid so. You can look at this page to add line numbers to your word document https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-line-numbers-b67cd35e-422c-42eb-adc9-256ca9802e22